# Automatically updating timer/ automatically resetting timer

Tags: javascript, date

I have a countdown timer implemented with JavaScript and I would like to edit it so that the timer resets once it expires every day at 10 a.m. So every day at 10 a.m. the timer should restart.

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 2, 2021 10:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("owntimer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("owntimer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

Currently, it is showing "Expired" once the timer is finished and I tried to replace it with a code that gets the current time, adds 24 hours, and replaces the date for the variable countDownDate. Unfortunately, that didn't work. I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: The method you described should work - how did you add the 24 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick snippet that implements a reset. I wrapped your logic in a function that accepts an `endDate` in epoch time, on expiry it adds a day (8.64e7 ms) to the initially supplied endDate and re-calls the function.

A few notes:

- It is best to call `new Date()` with either an epoch time in ms, or date component values if you can, to avoid any inconsistencies in parsing a date string.
- The current time can be retrieved with `Date.now()` rather than having to create a new Date object on every iteration.
- Since you are only changing the text value you can use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` (see: [differences from innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML)) to avoid triggering a reflow on every tick and the DOM having to parse it as HTML.

```js
const setTimer = (endDate) => {
  var x = setInterval(function () {

    // Get today's date and time
    var now = Date.now();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = endDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("owntimer").textContent = days + "d " + hours + "h "
      + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is finished, write some text
    if (distance <= 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("owntimer").textContent = "EXPIRED";
      const nextEndDate = endDate + 8.64e7
      setTimer(nextEndDate)
    }
  }, 1000);
}

var countDownDate = new Date(2021, 0, 2, 10, 00, 00).getTime();
// setTimer(countDownDate)

// set to now+10 seconds for demo
setTimer(Date.now()+1e4)
```

```html
<div id="owntimer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the extra 24 hours (remember to do it in milliseconds) and testing if have reached 0 difference (not just <) and not clearing the timer, since we want to continue ticking away, gives the correct result.

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 2, 2021 10:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("owntimer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, update to the next 24 hours
  if (distance <=0) { //need to catch the exact moment it goes to zero, hence <= not just <
    //clearInterval(x); //don't clear the interval, we want to carry on ticking away
    //document.getElementById("owntimer").innerHTML = "EXPIRED"; // this was just for debugging
    countDownDate = countDownDate + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="owntimer"></div>
```